# using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets from Mono?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, mono, xbuild

In an attempt to use the `TransformWebConfig` and `Package` tasks from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publishing.targets in a Mono-based CI build, I took a dependency on the `MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.target` NuGet package and updated my project file to Import it. The build works fine with MSBuild, but xbuild is unable to process the targets file:

> Unable to parse condition "'$(EnableWebPublishProfileFile)'=='true' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' != '' And Exists($(WebPublishProfileFile))" : Expected a property at position 90 in condition "'$(EnableWebPublishProfileFile)'=='true' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' != '' And Exists($(WebPublishProfileFile))". Missing opening parantheses after the '$'.

Actually, this is the error when I explicitly try to import `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets`; it is normally imported transitively by importing `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`. I think xbuild is failing (silently) to load the former when I just import the latter, as I simply get the error:

> error : Target named 'TransformWebConfig' not found in the project.

Again, this build works fine with MSBuild. The project file has the following Import directive:
`<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets\tools\VSToolsPath\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />`

Comment: xbuild is not MSBuild, so you should accept the fact that it is buggy and could not do whatever. Mono guys welcome community contribution, so if you like you can fix those bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does seem to be a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19678) in the xbuild conditional parsing logic. It looks like this can be worked around with single quotes around variable inside the Exists

```
Exists('$(WebPublishProfileFile)')
```